# Need way to statistic puzzle

Tags: statistics, puzzle, random

I need help with a statistic problem.
The problem is:

A room has 3 doors. One door leads to the room's exit in 0 minutes, the second door will lead us back to the same room after 3 minutes, and last door will return us to
the room after 6 minutes.

After opening one of doors we don't remember which
one was it. In other words, the probability to choose each door is *always* $\dfrac13$. (We choose a door randomly each time.)

What is the average time in minutes to exit from the room?

It says the answer is **10**, but don't know how they got it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the expected value of the time to exit.  If $t$ is the expected time, you have $1/3$ chance of choosing each door.  If you choose one of the ones that does not exit, you are back where you started, so $t=\frac 13 \cdot 0 + \frac 13 (t+3) + \frac 13(t+6)$  From this I get $9$, not $10$, minutes.

Comment: No, 
example:
i choose door with 3 minutes i return to room after 3 minutes
now i choose door with 6 minutes so i 9 minutes in room total
i back to room and choose again room 3 so i 12 minutes in room..
and etc...

but the question is which value the minutes convergence with all the options that in the end we choose room with 0 minutes (the exit)

there is infinity options but its convergence to 10

Comment: You are using the word convergence, but that is not correct.  The chance we exit at 10 minutes is zero, as every step is a multiple of 3.  What you have is a probability distribution of times spent.  The chance of spending 0 minutes is $1/3$ because you might pick the right door the first time.  The chance of spending $3$ minutes is $1/9$ because you have to pick the $3$ minute door followed by the $0$ minute door.  The chance of $6$ is $4/27$ and so on.  We can compute the expectation value of this distribution, which is $9$.

Comment: Alternatively, the exit-time is $S_N=X_1+...+X_N$, where the $X_i$ are iid Uniform on $\{0,3,6\}$ and $N=\min\{i:X_i=0\}\sim\text{Geometric}(1/3)$. By [Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation) we have $ES_N=EN\cdot ES_1$, and both of the means on the RHS equal $3$, giving $ES_N=9.$